# What is the performance expense of string comparisons for INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged, string-comparison

I was wondering about why MS decided to use strings in the design of INotifyPropertyChanged?

My initial worry was the large expense of doing string comparisons on every change notification, and I was wondering whether to keep my property names short to help with the comparisons.

However, given that strings are immutable in .Net, I wondered whether the runtime is intelligent enough to reuse string instances via some kind of hash table, so comparisons are effectively just a reference compare?

Does anyone know the implementation details, or if not, why MS designed it the way they did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it wasn't a `string`, what would you propose? It can't be a `PropertyInfo`, since not all types that support this use static typing - for example, a `DataTable` exposes a custom property model for binding purposes, as no many other types (via any of `ICustomTypeDescriptor`, `TypeDescriptionProvider`, or `ITypedList`).

Even if it **was** a `PropertyInfo`, or even if it was a `PropertyDescriptor`, you couldn't do a comparison on this: a: it would take a **lot** of work to obtain the reference lookup, b: you're not even guaranteed (for `PropertyDescriptor` in particular) to get back the same object every time you look.

So that means, you'd probably end up comparing the name (a `string`) **anyway**.

By using a `string`, it is cheap to raise this event, and pretty cheap to compare - a string compare is pretty fast, given that most property names are pretty short, and almost all are less than 30 characters. That will compare alarmingly fast, and it not a bottleneck. In most cases, the "what to do now it has changed" will take a **lot** more time than this string comparison.

I don't have the implementation in front of me, but I would **hope** that the string equality check is basically:

- same reference? return true
- different length? return false
- compare char-by-char; return false at first difference
- return true

so it shouldn't even be a problem unless all your property names are a: the same length, and b: a very significant length

Basically: don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you generate a new string, it will occupy its own space in memory, no matter if a string with the same content already exists.

On the other hand when you explicitly assign a string variable to another one, only the reference is being copied. Using constants is another way to save memory.

Reusing instances through a mechanism like a hash table would require a much larger overhead and comparision mechanisms, that would be called whenever a string is being created. This probably would most of the time be much more of a performance issue than to just store another couple of bytes.

Comment: What about strings that are Interned?

Comment: Not always true: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/28/string-interning-and-string-empty.aspx

Comment: @HarisHasan references can be explicitly retrieved with `String.Intern`.

Comment: I am a bit confused `Whenever you generate a new string, it will occupy its own space in memory, no matter if a string with the same content already exists.` When we say string literals may or may not be automatically interned does, this mean above statement is not correct?

Comment: @HarisHasan My statement is very broad and definitely does not apply to each and every scenario you can think of. I decided to keep the answer simple. Feel free to have a look at the documentation for special cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you're that concerned with implementation details, you can use Telerik's JustDecompile and see how they did it.
As far as why strings in INotifyPropertyChanged, the answer is reflection. I doubt they keep a reference to gain performance for a practically trivial task. What's the amount of notifications you're talking about? A normal WPF/SL application has no performance issues due to string comparisons in INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 2):

> why MS designed it the way they did?

Because they needed a flexible approach and it is fast enough. There are quite a few things going on when a property changes, the lookup of the string won't be the bottleneck.

The properties are registered in some base structure, the lookup will be like a Dictionary meaning that the HashCode will provide efficient access. The strings will all be interned but that is not reliable enough to determine in-equality from the references.

Keeping property names short won't bring any measurable improvement, better to use meaningful names.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider the consumers -- if you're a databound grid, you already have the property name as a string for the columns you're interested in. Also consider raising the event -- to get a `PropertyInfo` is not cheap, whilst hardcoding a string is.

Answer (score 0):

I think string comparison is not expensive at all compared to other mechanisms (such as bindings), so strings are definitely not a bottleneck.

That said, using constant strings in your code (I mean `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyProperty"))`) is fast, but I personally prefer using reflection to dynamically get the name of a property: it requires more work, but it greatly improves maintainability and reduces the amount of bugs (the most common is "I rename my property but I forget to change the parameter of the `PropertyChanged` event").

Answer (score 0):

There is a string interning in C#. Thanks to it the next code example will show you reference equality for equal strings created differently. So comparing same strings in simple scenarios should be very cheap.

```
using System;

public class A
{
    public string Title = "";
}

static public class Program {
    static public void Main() {
        var a = nameof(A.Title);
        var b = "Ti" + "tle";

        Console.WriteLine($"{a == b}, {object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)}");
    }
}
```